# CSS centered text

Tags: css

Yellow bar is `width:100%` header

I would like to achieve **MAIN TEXT** to be always **CENTERED** no matter the side text's length.

Margins between text are 100px

Image:

[image]

Thanks in advance

EDIT : HTML and CSS so far:

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div id="top"></div>
    Text Logo
    <span id="mainText"> Menu Links </span>
    Username: <?php echo $uname; ?>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    #mainText {

    margin-right:100px;
    margin-left:100px;

    }
```

Comment: please post your HTML and CSS

Comment: @Curt Added. It is nothing special yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand may be that's you want.

**CSS**

```
.left{
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    background:green;
}
.middle{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline/*For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:red;
    margin:0 100px;
}
.parent{
    text-align:center;
}
.parent div{
    text-align:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <p class="left">L side Text</p>
 <p class="middle">Center side Text</p>
 <p class="right">R side Text</p>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/XhMtK/3/

**UPDATED**

May that's you want

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/XhMtK/4/

Comment: Yes, but as i can see here, centered text moves, depending on length of side texts.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can used float as like this

**CSS**

```
.one{
width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
    text-align:center;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
    width:20%;

}

.center{
    margin:0 auto;
    background:pink;
    width:50%;




}

.right{
    float:right;
    background:red;
    width:20%;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/JNxsZ/2/
    ​